# How to upload file using RoboSpice Google Http Java Client module with JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json, robospice, google-http-client

I'm using `RoboSpice Google Http Java Client module` and I'm successfully executing `POST` request using `JSON` data.

**Problem :**  My problem is now I've to attach `byte[]` data in `POST` request but I'm unable to find any way to do this with `RoboSpice Google Http Java Client module`.

**Here is my code snippet :**

```
public class SaveUserProfile_Request extends GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest<SaveUserProfile> {
    private String apiUrl;
    private JSONObject mJsonObject;
    private String filePath;

    public SaveUserProfile_Request(JSONObject mJsonObject, String filePath) {
    super(SaveUserProfile.class);
    this.apiUrl = AppConstants.GLOBAL_API_BASE_ADDRESS + AppConstants.API_SAVE_PROFILE;
    this.mJsonObject = mJsonObject;
    this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public SaveUserProfile loadDataFromNetwork() throws IOException {
    Ln.d("Call web service " + apiUrl);

    HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(apiUrl),
        ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", mJsonObject.toString()));

    request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());

    return request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
    }

}
```

I tried using `Multipart HTTP Requests` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17151284/881771
You can add the FileUpload logic to your loadFromNetwork method before calling

```
request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
```